# Roslyn Analyzer to mark return type of property

Tags: c#, roslyn-code-analysis

I'm writing an analyzer for Roslyn that needs to mark the return type of a property.  I have it marking the property declaration itself.  I've looked through the debugger but I can't find a location that targets the return type token.

Example:

```
// important code for analzyer

public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
{
    context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(AnalyzeSyntax, SyntaxKind.MethodDeclaration, SyntaxKind.PropertyDeclaration);
}

private static void AnalyzeSyntax(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
{
    var propertySymbol = context.ContainingSymbol as IPropertySymbol;
    var propertyType = propertySymbol.Type;
    if (propertyType.Name != "Class1") return;

    var diagnostic = Diagnostic.Create(Rule, propertySymbol.Locations[0], propertyType.Name);
    context.ReportDiagnostic(diagnostic);
    break;
}

// example where it should be working

public class Usage
{
    public Class1 Test { get; set; }
}
```

It currently puts green squigglies under the `Usage.Test` property name, but I want it under the return type for that property.

The `context.ContainingSymbol` has a `Locations` property, but it only has one location specified in it, and it points exclusively to `Test`.  The `context.Node` specifies a few other spans that cover the entire property, but it's not a full `Location` object, so I can't use them.

**Edit 1**

Apparently, it's important that I'm doing this in .Net Standard with VS 2017.  The .Net 4.5 analyzers can access usages via the `MSBuildWorkspace` and `SymbolFinder` classes, but .Net Standard doesn't have `MSBuildWorkspace` for some reason so I can't get the current solution to pass to `SymbolFinder.FindReferencesAsync()`.

Comment: Did you try just `propertyType.Locations[0]`? If it still doesn't work for you you can retrieve corresponding declaration syntax node of your property (propertySymbol.DeclaringSyntaxReferences[0]) and just look at return type node in it

Comment: Yeah, `propertyType.Locations[0]` is what I have in my code now, but it doesn't appear to produce a report (compiler warning, in my case).  I don't see how to get to a return type node in the syntax references.  The only public members are `Span` and `SyntaxTree` which are less than useful.

Comment: On the report now being produced, I mean that I submit it to the `ReportDiagnostics()` method, but nothing happens.  No squigglies and no compiler warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The context.Node specifies a few other spans that cover the entire property, but it's not a full Location object, so I can't use them.

The answer lies in creating a `Location` from a `TextSpan`.  To do this, you can use `Location.Create()` which takes in the syntax tree and the span.  Both of these are available through the `context.Node` property.

```
var propertyTypeIdentifier = ((PropertyDeclarationSyntax) context.Node).Type;

name = propertyType.Name;
location = Location.Create(propertyTypeIdentifier.SyntaxTree, propertyTypeIdentifier.Span);
```